# Dereferencing an atom in a 'case' expression

Tags: clojure

This returns true:

```
(def a (atom 1))
(case @a 1 true false)
```

but this returns false:

```
(def a (atom 1))
(case 1 @a true false)
```

Shouldn't the 2nd expression return true?

*Answer*:
Explanation by @Carcigenicate: "every second argument to case need to be a compile-time literal".
@a is not, so the `case` expression must be replaced with a `if`:

```
(def a (atom 1))
(if (= 1 @a) true false))
```

Comment: The `case`s being matched on need to be compile-time literals. My Clojure is quite rusty, but I believe it's treating `@a` as a symbol in the second case, since you're trying to use `@a`, which needs to be evaluated at runtime, as a symbol that's interpreted by a macro at macro-expansion time. Every second argument to `case` (except the last) [need to be a compile-time literal](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/case): "The test-constants are not evaluated. They must be compile-time
literals, and need not be quoted."

Comment: I'm not sure the [atomic] tag is appropriate; does this have anything to do with atomicity of operations from the perspective of other threads or whatever, being indivisible either all-or-nothing?   I think this usage of "atom" is about the smallest parsing(?) unit, not about concurrency.  But I don't know clojure or this type of language and terminology.

Comment: @PeterCordes An atom is a way of swapping values (the swap is atomic). It's for sharing data across threads, but without needing to manually lock the resource (the language handles it).

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Ok, thanks, then the tag is appropriate.  Calling the value being swapped an "atom" isn't how other languages describe it, but it is consistent with the normal meaning (from the Greek meaning "indivisible".)

Comment: @Carcigenicate FWIW `@a` is a reader macro for `(clojure.core/deref a)`. So the case doesn't match a single symbol, but either of the two symbols `a` and `clojure.core/deref`.

Comment: @amalloy Ah, thanks,I knew I was forgetting something.

Comment: Both `(case @a 1 true false)` and `(= @a 1)` are valid. No need for the `if`.

Comment: @Thumbnail Yes, but I oversimplified the original code which was more like: `(case @a @b 1 @c 2 @d 3 ...)`. Now replaced with a nested if.

Comment: @Francois Clojure has a `cond` macro that does `if` nesting for you. In this case, a variant called `condp` works even better: `(condp = @a @b 1 @c 2 @d 3 ...)`. You can use this pattern wherever you would like to use a `case` form but the matches are not compile-time constants.